# Twilio QuickStarter project issue in ios

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

i have downloaded the twilio quickstarter project and followed the docx and create the function for chat and pass the url to the given place in project, now when i run the app the app crashes with this error,`Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1048d85b0)`. This error comes in their code when it try to seralize the data from the request. How can i get out from this issue?. This is the code where issue is occurring,

```
struct TokenUtils {

static func retrieveToken(url: String, completion: @escaping (String?, String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    if let requestURL = URL(string: url) {

        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: requestURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String]
                    let token = json["token"]
                    let identity = json["identity"]
                    completion(token, identity, error)
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    completion(nil, nil, error)
                }

            } else {
                completion(nil, nil, error)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

}

This is what it shows in debugger,
[image]

Comment: Could you add the error you get on the debugger?

Comment: i have mention the in my question above Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1048d85b0) . It comes on this line let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String]. @SylvanDAsh

Comment: print what you got for json. Make sure it has keys like token and  identity or will crash

Comment: it crashes before printing the json. On this line let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String]. @user3344236

Comment: @Hamza on the top right of Xcode, there are 3 buttons that hide/show panels. The middle one shows the debug area. And the debug area has 2 panels: `Console` and `Variables view`. The *console* will print a more detailed description of the error you're getting. Paste this error for us

Comment: Bro i know about the console but the the app crashes and does not show any error in console. It just stop at this line  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String] , by showing this on the line, Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1048d85b0)

Comment: Bro i know about the console but the the app crashes and does not show any error in console. It just stop at this line  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String] , by showing this on the line, Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1048d85b0) . @SylvanDAsh

Comment: OK. Try changing `as! [String: String]` to `as? [String: String]`. Might be an issue with the force-casting

Comment: The error is removed but in console i get , error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." @SylvanDAsh

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this should mean that the address you've provided for your chat app isn't correct...

Comment: i have created the function from twilio platform and they have given me this url. @SylvanDAsh

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an iOS device with me at the moment, so I can test their ChatQuickstart and give you more accurate feedback on it. The best option is to erase everything and rewrite it all again (in case it's a simple mistake you've made). OR contact their support team